# How can an AVL tree have a complexity of O(log n) when the in-order traversal calls itself recursively twice? Doesn't that make it O(2^n)?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I have an AVL tree which holds player objects. Each player has a name and a rank. The tree nodes are ordered based on player rank. I traverse the tree depth first and append each node to a list of players ordered by rank (in descending order hence the right to left traversal).

Everything I read tells me that an AVL tree has a complexity of O(log n), but when I look at my in-order traversal function I note that it calls itself recursively twice which I thought would make it O(2^n). Is there a more efficient way to traverse the tree that I don't know about? or am I wrong with my big O calculations?

```
def traverseRightToLeft(node, array = []):
# Base case
if node is None:
    return
# Recursively check if there are any right child nodes, append the current node data to the list then recursively check if there are any left child nodes
else:
    traverseRightToLeft(node.right, array)
    array.append(node.data)
    traverseRightToLeft(node.left, array)
return array
```

Comment: The O(log n) usually relates to a single item tree search. You're traversing over the whole tree.

Comment: Usain Bolt can run 100m in under 10 seconds, but he surely can't run a marathon in that time. There is no such thing as the time complexity of a data structure, only the time complexities of each thing you can do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining *n* as number of nodes in a tree.

Operations like **Search**, **Insert** and **Erase** are `O(log n)` in an AVL Tree.

Traverse a tree is `O(n)`, no matter if it's an AVL Tree, a B-Tree or a Red Black Tree, because you recurse in every node only once (the call of the parent node or the initial call to the root).

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is the statement "calling yourself recursively twice makes the algorithm O(2^n)".  This is not true.  The algorithm is calling itself recursively on something half its size.

Imagine I want to count n blocks.  I can just count the n blocks.  Or I can split them into two roughly equal sets, and then count the left side and then count the right side and add them.  If the left side or right side is too big, I can recursively split either (or both) of them in half, and count roughly quarter separately.  But I'm still only counting every element once.